# How to convert plain text to html but keep the display format?

Tags: html

I have one plain text which is program output, but I want to display it in html page. But still I want to keep the formats (like space/tab/enter and etc.), it's just like the code block of stackoverflow, how can I display it properly in html ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "pre" and "code" HTML tags:

```
<pre><code>   code in here...  </code></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<code>    the program</code>`

Comment: Thanks, just found out <pre><code> fit my requirement